# Should this SE be renamed?

Tags: discussion

Is "expats" a suitable name for this site? Expats is just a politically correct word for immigrant. It mostly exists because immigrant has negative connotations and white people don't want to be called that.

Keeping the name just re-enforces this. The site is about questions that immigrants have and shouldn't use harmful politically correct language. It's harmful because it perpetuates the idea that there is some difference between an expat and an immigrant.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that there have been previous attempts to have a StackExchange site for 'Immigration' and related topics, but those sites never made it long into their Beta stages. There are probably numerous reasons for that - sometimes it's just luck or bad timing. For whatever reason, when the Expats proposal went through, it got some real traction with users. Perhaps it was the name that appealed to a wider audience. Not sure, but all long-term visa topics ended up here as well as topics on citizenship and residence. It's just the way things have worked out.

Comment: "It mostly exists because immigrant has negative connotations" - Maybe to you. But not to me. And not to many people I know, including the vast majority of my neighbors and colleagues, most of whom are native born English. Got a link to that assertion? "white people don't want to be called that." I see. You mean like English immigrants, Polish immigrants, Canadian immigrants, Romanian, etc...? I think this is again an idea that exists in your head and no one else's.

Answer (score 5):

"Expatriates" covers the case of someone living temporarily abroad, whereas "immigrants" does not. This site covers many cases that are not "immigrants". For example in the US system short term work visas like H1B, student F visas, company transfer L and exchange visitor J are all non-immigrant visas, and people living in the US under their terms are not called "immigrants" in normal speech. We answer questions about them.

"Expatriates" is not just a politically correct name for immigrants. "Expatriates" as a word has been around for hundreds of years before "political correctness" was even thought of.

It would be weird to expect a user to come to a site called "Immigration" to ask about non-immigrant circumstances.

**No it should not be renamed.** Or at least not to "Immigration" or anything similar.

However I will say that "Expatriates" is not a common word and may not be understood by people who have English as a second language. It's possible that a change to "Living Abroad" or something similar might be helpful.